# Macbook M1 Gray Login Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, filevault

I have a MacBook Air M1. After around 10 months suddenly the login screen is showing a grey background screen. I looked around on the Apple forum, and it was because I turned on FileVault. I checked it up, but the FileVault is off. How to fix this?

[image: image of macbook screen]

Comment: FileVault doesn't make it grey in the first place. You could try safe mode and an external screen to check whether its a software or hardware issue

Answer (score 1):

Solved, it is monterey problem. I updated to Ventura and it all fixed.